# Loading partial on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to load a partial (_unansweredquestions.html.erb) on a click. No error is showing but when clicked nothing happens.

Here is the link (its the correct path):

```
<%= link_to "Load", unansweredquestions_post_comment_path, id: "new_link", :remote => true %>
```

here is unansweredquestions.js.erb:

```
$('#new_link').html("<%= render :partial => 'unansweredquestions' %>");
```

and here are the routes:

```
resources :comments do
 member do 
  get :unansweredquestions
 end
end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#new_link').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'unansweredquestions') %>");
```

or in `Rails 4`, you can do in this way

```
$('#new_link').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'unansweredquestions') %>");
```